# Why HashiCorp vault returning null?

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I have a HashiCorp vault setup and it seems to return `null` all the time except when I ssh into the VM and then I set the values again followed by checking the values directly on the vault server.

Any ideas what might be happening?

I am a bit lost on this and not even sure what logs or config files are helpful. This is one of my first experiences with vault and so far it seems finicky at best.

Comment: Are you sure that you (or your instance) has the correct permissions? Vault can be  opaque in its errors that it outputs....

Comment: @PrestonM I'm not sure about that, I have tried with the root token so that should work fine. It works sometimes once I re-put in the data but then it is like it expires nearly right away but I am not putting any lease on it. If I read right the generic secret backend doesn't have leases by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unsure what happened, try deploying it in AWS via [AWS vault quickstarts](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/vault/). They deploy vault end-to-end, so now you can compare it to yours and find out what was the problem.